# How to permanently focus an element?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a page where a button or an input field is the most important element on the page. I know that I can automatically focus the element when the page loads by using the `autofocus` attribute:

```
<button autofocus>Hello!</button>
```

This works as advertised, but unfortunately, the HTML element will lose focus if the user clicks on any other part of the page.

How can I permanently focus a HTML element?

(Note: if JavaScript really needs to be used to accomplish this task, please show the solution using plain JavaScript [i.e. without jQuery]).

EDIT: I am making a personal application where there is only ever going to be one button on the page, and nothing else. The focus will allow me to quickly "press" the button using the keyboard (e.g. by pressing the enter key) at any time.

Comment: *"the element will lose focus if the user clicks on any other part of the page"* Good. :-) The browser is the *user's* agent, not yours. If they want to focus a different part of the page, let them. I'd strongly recommend not interfering in the user's focus action, both philosophically and pragmatically (focus wars get ugly cross-browser *fast*).

Comment: You'd essentially be rendering the rest of the page inaccessible. Doesn't seem like a good UX strategy.

Comment: There's a use case for everything, people. Flux could be building a game that requires one element to remain in focus the entire time for all we know.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's actually for a personal application where there is only ever going to be one button on the page, and nothing else. Focus helps in quickly pressing the button using the keyboard (e.g. using the enter key).

Comment: @JonUleis - The very reason I posted an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832614/how-to-permanently-focus-an-element#comment98329897_55832614). I'd strongly recommend not doing this in the general case, but yours sounds like quite a specific case in a well-controlled environment.

You can hook the `blur` event on the button and try to give it focus again:

```js
document.querySelector("button[autofocus]").addEventListener("blur", function() {
    var t = this;
    t.focus();
    setTimeout(function() { // Some browsers won't let you do it until
        t.focus();          // after the blur has completed
    }, 100);
});
```

```html
<button autofocus>This is the button</button>
<button>Another button</button> just so we can see that it works if we tab away from the first one.
```

Or use an interval timer, etc.

Comment: That's write this works I was using prevent default on blur so I create click solution.

Comment: Your concerns are valid, but as I said, I am going to be the only user of the intended application, and the application is only going to consist of one button (yes, one button and nothing else).

Comment: @Flux - Fair enough! :-) It's often helpful to provide that kind of context in the question (toward the end), so people know the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Heed the warnings in the comments.

```
document.getElementById('stayHere').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.focus();
});
```

You could potentially do this with CSS to some extent, also:

```
body {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.greedy-button {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option is JavaScript like this:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(!e.target.matches('button[autofocus]')) {
    button.focus();
  }
})
```

```html
<button autofocus>focus</button>
```

Comment: Pressing `tab` moves focus off the button, without triggering `click`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yea, your solution is better, my first try was blur but with `e.preventDefault()` but it was not working, so I've though that blur is not working on button.

Comment: Ah, yeah. They don't allow you to prevent taking focus away. (On some browsers, `blur` only fires after it's already happened, IIRC...)